# jQuery modal dialog using different styles?

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

When we display our grid (jqGrid) in a jQuery modal dialog it uses different styles (font size specifically) versus the grid displayed on our main screen.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explictly seting the jq grid style in the table definition - `class="ui-jqgrid"` -  seems to work:

```
<div style="display:none" id="dialog-activity">
<table class="ui-jqgrid" id="tact_list"></table>
<div id="tact_pager"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does **jqGrid** had wrong font size bevore? You wrote in your question about **different sizes**, so I supposed that jqGrid has like allways 11px, but the other fonts in the dialog was too large. If jqGrid had wrong size because of CSS inharitance you shoud better write the information in your question. If you write your question too short it produces frequently more work for people who answers. Moreover pasting of a code fragment could explains mostly much more as a long description. So please include code examples in the future and try be more exact in your questions. It will help all.

Comment: Will do Oleg.  Yes, the jqGrid fonts in the main screen were size n and the jqGrid fonts in the dialog were n+1..

Answer (score 1):

It is OK jqGrid is a **jQuery plugin** and not a **jQuery UI widget**, but jqGrid use jQuery UI styles and so the look is very close. Not the same, but close.

You can include some code in your question, then one could help you.

**UPDATED**: jqGrid use **`font-size:11px`** in the dialogs which it displays. You can use the same CSS setting for jQuery UI dialogs and overwrite default **1.1em** value. To do this you can include in your CSS

```
.ui-widget { font-size: 11px !important; }
```